# Angular stateprovider resolve not passing data to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

So I have a problem with angular ui.router, which apparently isn't passing the data from resolve to controller. I have the following state set up:

```
$stateProvider
.state('myState', {
  url: "/myUrl",
  templateUrl: "myTemplate",
  controller: 'myController',
  resolve: {
    randomData: function($q, $sails) {
      var defer = $q.defer();
      $sails.get("/me")
      .success(function(data) {
        console.log(data)    // prints out actual data
        defer.resolve(data);
      })
      return defer.promise;
    }
  }
```

and in `myController` I basically have

```
myApp.controller('myController', [
  '$scope', function ($scope, randomData) {
     console.log("randomData:" + randomData)
        // prints out 'randomData: undefined'
     }
])
```

According to every doc, stackoverflow post and tutorial, this piece of code should work, but it keeps printing undefined. Does anyone have an idea why this isn't working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to inject the data in the array notation:

```
myApp.controller('myController', [
    '$scope', 'randomData', // <-- this one
    function ($scope, randomData) {
        console.log("randomData:" + randomData);
    }
])
```

Comment: Well, that's that. Simple mistakes like this really make my blood boil :c Will accept your answer once I can.